# create a list of dictionaries from two lists of tuples

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a set of tuples:

```
users = set(("test@a.com","password"),("test@b.com","password"))
```

but could be simplified to a set...and a list of tuples:

```
licences = [("test@a.com","22"),("test@a.com","23"),("test@b.com","12")]
```

For every entry of the list the username could be repeated with different "licence" values.

I need to build a list of dictionaries like this:

```
[{"user":"test@a.com", "licences":["22","23"]},{"user":"test@b.com", "licences":["12"]}]
```

What I've done so far is this:

```
licenzadiz = []
for num,user in enumerate(users):
    licenzadiz.append({'user': user[0], 'licences': []})
    for num2,licence in enumerate(licences):
        if user[0] == licence[0]:
            licenzadiz[num]['licences'].append(licence[1])
```

that is working well. BUT I wonder if there are more elegant solutions to my problem.

Comment: Pls provide sample input for the output in your example!

Comment: What is utenti and utente?

Comment: Please provide [MCVE] for your set of tuples and list of tuples, along with expected output given shown demo input. We should be able to copy and paste it to interpreter without any problem.

Comment: @ŁukaszRogalski now it should be better, apologizes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get fancy with nested default dicts:

```
from collections import defaultdict

items = [('A','1'),('A','3'),('A','2'),
         ('B','0'),('B','4'),('B','-1'),
         ('C','7'),('C','6'),('C','12')]

d = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(list))

for use,lic in items:
    d[use]['username'] = use #<-- Overwrites each time an already known key is found, but thats ok
    d[use]['licence'].append(lic)


#Just for printout
for use in d:
    print d[use]
    print d[use]['username']
    print d[use]['licence']
```

Output:

```
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'username': 'A', 'licence': ['1', '3', '2']})
A
['1', '3', '2']
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'username': 'C', 'licence': ['7', '6', '12']})
C
['7', '6', '12']
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'username': 'B', 'licence': ['0', '4', '-1']})
B
['0', '4', '-1']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
data = {}
for num2,(email, license) in enumerate(licenze):
    data.setdefault(email,[]).append(license)

print data #dictionary of email:[licenses,..]
#or 
print data.items() # if you want a list
```

I guess ... i think